# D DMD error messages don't get parsed?

Tags: editor, d

Sometimes SciTE (and also Programmers notepad) stop handling error messages that DMD.exe outputs.

What I found is, that they are both unable to jump to line 81 in game.d here:
"game.d(81): some error"

whereas this one works:
"game.d(81) : some error"

There's just an aditional space before the colon. Do you know how I could make SciTE forgive the missing space? Or could I make DMD output a space before the colon?

Comment: in the regex for the parser add a ` ?` (that is a space and a question mark) before the colon

Comment: Thanks! Do I have to compile SciLexer.dll to add this?

Comment: Compiling seems the only way for Scintilla based editors.
One editor that's able to understand the DMD output is Crimsoneditor.

Comment: If the regex is a string literal, you might be able to patch the DLL with a hex editor :)

Comment: FWIW The Zeus editor handles the DMD error output.

Answer (score 2):

Try [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/). It is pretty good at this.